# What is the lightest collection for store these values?

Tags: c#, .net

I have many objects (such as 10.000, more or less). Every object has3 values :

1. Index (decimal, such as 0,0 <= X <= 100.000,9);
2. A Latitude value;
3. A Longitude value;

and I need to perform some search due to the Index value. Which will be the light approch to this? `List<MyObject>`? I know there are hashtable, but only for 2 values...

I read these values from a .csv file and I'll store it on application. WebForm, .NET 4.5.

Comment: lightest? Are you talking about RAM, disk storage (if you're saving to disk), or search performance? A hash table is for storing key/value pairs, and the key and the value can be any object you wish, as long as you implement getHashCode(). Without knowing what "some search" is, there's not much to say.

Comment: As I said, I'll read it from a csv, and put them in Application. So, RAM and search performance (for the further search).

Comment: Perform search due to the Index value (example search Lat/Lng at 4,5)

Comment: What are your constraints? How fast does this have to be? How much memory may the application consume at worst? Why do you think that an approach that is not 'light' would be a problem? Have you tested the performance of the `List<MyObject>`?

Comment: What do you want to do with your data? Seach for it by index? By latitude? By longitude? Do you need good search performance? Good insertion performance? If you're not more specific in what you're trying to achieve, you're not going to get helpful answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a Dictionary like this:

```
public class Position
{
    public Latitude  Latitude  { get ; set ; }
    public Longitude Longitude { get ; set ; }
}

public Dictionary<decimal,Position> Positions ;
```

Or use a Tuple in the dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<decimal,Tuple<Latitude,Longitude>> Positions ;
```

Comment: This was my first idea... but maybe there were somethings more light? I don't know, that's why I asked :)

Answer (score 4):

The very lightest approach in terms of memory use is to put these into a struct, and hold them in an array of such structs. From what you say, you can't really pack data any tighter than that: two doubles and a decimal will occupy 32 bytes per entry, and the array of structs does not add any per-item overhead on top of this.

Having said that, this will slow down your coding and might save too little to matter in practice.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the absolutely lightest approach would be bitmasking your values into an unsigned long, though it is slightly cumbersome.

To really get the grasp on which is the most efficient approach, i recommend trying them all with test values and looking at the output of sizeof() on them. that way you'd be really sure what's their runtime memory size.

I'd suggest a custom struct to hold your values, a tuple could work as well.

Comment: And store single tuple where? on a List<>?

Comment: Yes, but depends mostly on whether you want write or read speed. A linked list will provide burning fast insertions, while an array-based list will provide the fastest reads at a hefty price of slow insertions because of readjustments (Unless you know how much array elements you will need before inserting all of them at once)